# iPhone as 'headphones' for computer

Tags: iphone, streaming, ethernet, audio

I have been using headphones with an external USB sound card, but the sound card broke today, and my other audio ports are messed up.

I have an iPhone, and I know that [a computer with a wireless card can stream it's audio to an iPhone](http://mac.appstorm.net/how-to/music/using-your-iphone-as-wireless-headphones/), but can a computer without a wireless card (on an ethernet connection) use this or a similar service to send audio to an iPhone? Maybe even a tethered iPhone, because I can do that.

Answer (score 2):

maybe look into [airfoil](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/) and its iOS companion app?

Comment: yes, this looks like exactly what I need.. do you know if airfoil will work with a computer that does not have a wireless connection so the computer is connected to the internet via ethernet?

Comment: i don't know for sure, i did some preliminary googling but couldn't find a definitive answer.  I know this is a cop out, but why not try the trial version?

Comment: I tried the trial version, but it just had the problem I though it would have: since the computer is not on the same network as the iPhone, it has no way of finding the iPhone as a place to send sound to... can I tether the iPhone to the computer, and somehow many a computer to computer network that way?

Comment: i doubt it, sorry.