# Is it possible to stream music TO an iPod touch via bluetooth?

Tags: ipod-touch, music, ipod, bluetooth, streaming

Say you have the iPod connected to a dock to your home stereo.  Is it possible to pair another bluetooth enabled device with it and stream music to the iPod?

In effect making the iPod like those Bluetooth adapters out there that add Bluetooth capability to the iPod dock.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sending audio from a Mac or PC this is very doable using the Rogue Amoeba product AirFoil:

- http://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/speakers.php

It doesn't go over bluetooth, but WiFi similar to AirPlay - but it might be the closest you can get without jailbreaking iOS. I don't know of a specific jailbreak mod, but it's not something iOS/OS X does natively.

You might also be in the situation of these other users:

- [iPhone as 'headphones' for computer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/37384/iphone-as-headphones-for-computer/37387#37387)
- [Connect iphone to multiple output devices to play music](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/131078/connect-iphone-to-multiple-output-devices-to-play-music/131083#131083)

For sending bluetooth audio to a home receiver, I'd spend the money for a dedicated device like Belkin's as it remembers up to 6 paired devices and uses wall power. It's quite tiny even though the image below is large.

- [http://www.amazon.com/Belkin-Stream-Bluetooth-Music-Receiver/dp/B00IL7BWGA/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00IL7BWGA)

[image: Belkin]

Answer (score 0):

iPod Touch4 does a great job of transmitting BlueTooth 
natively as long as Bluetooth is enabled in *Settings*.
The first time a device is connected the iPod remembers it
as a pairable device and connection is automatic from there
on whenever that device requests connection. I have six pairable
devices but do not know if there is a maximum.
I am not aware that iPod can receive Bluetooth (as a playback
device) in its native state, but would like to know if there is a
Proven App that would do this .

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best. Explain why you think the answer you provided will solve the problem or is better than others out there.  Providing links can also help the OP, and others, find additional info for themselves.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review